# Using Linq to find only records that have all matching values in list of flags?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of records that have a list of 0 to many flags in each main record. I am trying to come up with a Linq query to bring back only the records that matches all the flags in the list of flags.

```
var flags = new List<string>() {"flag1","flag5"}; 
//The flags list could also be empty in which case it should match records with no flags set.
var tbs = db.MyContents
.Select(a => new  {a.Id, FlagList=a.Flags.Select(f=>f.Name).ToList()})
.Where(f=>f.FlagList.Intersect(flags).Any());
```

The above code brings back all the records that have `"flag1 ||flag5"` or `"flag1 && flag5"`. But what I want to do is bring back only those records that have both `"flag1 && flag5"`

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: there was an error in my code, i edited it please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Except` with NOT `Any` to make sure every value match from `flags` collection.

```
var tbs = db.MyContents
           .Select(a => new { a.Id, FlagList = a.Flags.Select(f => f.Name) })
           .Where(f => !flags.Except(f.FlagList).Any());
```

**EDIT**

I saw you edit your question, you just need to add some logic in linq `where`

```
var tbs = c.Select(a => new { a.Id, FlagList = a.Flags.Select(f => f.Name) })
               .Where(f => !flags.Except(f.FlagList).Any() && flags.Count() > 0 ||
                       flags.Count() == 0 && f.FlagList.Count() == 0);
```

Comment: This just returned all the records that had either/or or both. I need to return only those that have all.

Comment: This presumes that the flags list is populated. There is a chance that the flags list is empty and therefore needs to match records that have no flag set. (I know I didn't have that in my original post. sorry)

Comment: This actually brings back all the groups with a subset of flags when I want it to brign back a group with only the flags in my list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could have the `Where()` be:

`.Where(f=>f.FlagList.Intersect(flags).Count() == flags.Count());`

Comment: Does Intersect() not only get one of each value?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of `Records`, where every `Record` has a sequence of `Flags`. You also have another sequence of flags.

Example:

```
var oftherFlags = A B C
var records = record A with flags A B
              record B with flags A B C
              record C with flags   B C
              record D with flags A B C D
              record E with flags A A A A A B C
```

> "I want to come up with a Linq query to bring back all records that match all the flags"

Obviously record B is okay. Record A and C have some missing records; Do you want record D? It has all flags, it even has some more flags. Is that a problem? And how about record E? You forgot to specify anything about duplicates

Let's assume that all `Flag` sequence may have duplicates, and that you don't bother about duplicate.

Thus the following will give the same results

```
var otherFlags = A B C
var otherFlags = A B C C C C C
```

[HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the rescue!

```
IEnumerable<string> otherFlags = ...
var result = myRecords
    // put the flags in a HashSet, this removes duplicates
    .Select(record => new
    {
         Record = record,
         FlagSet = new HashSet<string>(record.Flags),
    })
    // keep only those elements where the FlagSet is a superset of otherFlags
    .Where(element => element.FlagSet.IsSuperSetOf(otherFlags)
    .Select(element => element.Record);
```

If duplicates should be taken into account, so if `otherFlags` has two A, and you only want the `Records` with two A, you could use `Enumerable.Except`

```
var result = myRecords
    .Where(record => record.Flags    // from every record take the flags
         .Except(otherFlags)         // remove all otherFlags
         .Any());                    // keep the record if there are still flags left
```